# Install docker on CentOS 8

Tags: docker, centos

I installed docker on CentOS 8. CentOS doesn't Docker anymore. When I type `docker build -t project .` than I get this error message:

```sh
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://http.debian.net/debian sid InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'http.debian.net'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/sid/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'http.debian.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
E: The value 'testing' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update      && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends groff     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I tried in /etc/resolv.conf `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Are you trying to build dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when you do docker build, docker internal will set up temp build container for you, so it still related to container's dns.

By default, docker will use dns locally defined in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but if not found, you may also have chance to override it.

You should create next file with the following contents to set DNS:

**/etc/docker/daemon.json:**

```
{
    "dns": ["your_dns_ip"]
}
```

Finally, **restart** your docker to make it take effect. Detail refers to [Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/).

Additionally, make sure you use a workable dns, also make sure `8.8.8.8` really could work in your country if you use this.